# creating alias for cmd with backticks

Tags: alias, tcsh

I'm working in tcsh. How do  I create an alias for:

```
nc stop `nc list | awk '/Running/{print $1}'`
```

I tried various variations of:

```
alias ncstop "nc stop `nc list | awk '/Running/{print $1}'`"
```

but none work

Comment: In your alias, the backticks will be evaluated too early (ie: when the alias is defined).

Comment: O.K. got it. what other way can I try to automate this cmd ?

Comment: In bash when i use ' (single quotes) in  alias i always had trouble... awk works even with double quotes... give them a try.

Comment: As with many comments here I come from a bash background, but whenever aliases are tricky it's probably a sign you should use a function instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the quoting a bit to not allow the backticks to be evaluated until when the alias is used.

```
alias ncstop 'nc stop `nc list | awk '\''/Running/{print $1}'\''`'
```

This works because when the `'` character is used for quoting, so that the special characters such as `|`, `$` and the `backtick` are not interpreted by the shell.  That allows those special characters to make it into the alias definition.  But in the process of defining the alias the shell removes that outer layer of `'`'s.  What actually ends up in the alias definition should be:

```
nc stop `nc list | awk '/Running/{print $1}'`
```

The `'\''` construct can often use a little explaining.  But in short it is three apostrophes.  The first ends the previous quoted string, the next (which is escaped so as to not be interpreted by the shell) passes through, and the third starts another quoted string.  So the `'\''` construct allows an apostrophe (ie: `'` or `single quote`) to appear inside of a single quoted string.

Getting all of the quotes and escapes right in a string that needs to traverse multiple layers of interpretation gets messy and complicated very quickly.  There was a comment on the question that recommended (for `bash`) looking into implementing aliases as functions instead.  I am pretty sure the same could be advised for `tcsh`.

Comment: doesnt work get error Unmatched `.  If backticks are quoted get error Unmatched "

Comment: I dont understand why this works

Comment: @galinakorosov, just added some explanation.  Let me know if it is still unclear.